# Clarification for the test and validation set

Tags: machine-learning, validation

I have been trying to figure out the difference between validation and test set used in the machine learning studies. In almost all places, I found that I have to split the dataset into three parts (ie. 50/20/20) ratio to obtain the training, validation, and test sets, respectively. However, I have a question that whether it would be possible if I do this following method in my study:

I split my data set into 80:20 for training and validation set. And then, I will use a completely new dataset (as an external set) for my test set.

Is it legit? Would appreciate any insight on this.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Why note consider your totally new data set as part of your data and then do a 60/20/20 split on all data?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt and insightful comment on this! I am trying to apply some kind of external validation of a prediction model that I build using my current dataset. That is why I was thinking to consider such totally new dataset as a test set to evaluate the model and whether it make sense to do. However, your point is great that I could combine the new dataset with my current set and then split to 60/20/20 ratio to obtain the training, validation, and test sets. Would proceed as you suggested!

Comment: [Cross-validation](http://stanfordphd.com/Cross-validation.html) is another possibility.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and sharing important information which is very helpful for me!